# How to define (or simulate) a collection containing different types in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Working on a project with SQLAlchemy, I was attempting to employ what I believe is a composition pattern. I have a class of "owner" objects; I encapsulate some functionality in component classes and give the owners different capabilities by assigning components to them. The owners and the components all have state that needs to be serialized, so they're all SQLAlchemy objects. Here's a simple example ([linked for readability](http://pastebin.com/1GsRhtak)):

```
class Employee(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class SalesRole(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_role'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    employee = relationship(
        'Employee',
        backref=backref('sales_role', uselist=False)
    )

    def __init__(self, employee):
        self.employee = employee
        self.total_sales = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<SalesRole(employee='%s')>" % self.employee.name

    # Sales-specific data and behavior
    total_sales = Column(Float)


class CustomerSupportRole(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'support_role'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    employee = relationship(
        'Employee',
        backref=backref('support_role', uselist=False)
    )

    def __init__(self, employee):
        self.employee = employee
        self.tickets_resolved = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<CustomerSupportRole(employee='%s')>" % self.employee.name

    # Support-specific data and behavior
    tickets_resolved = Column(Integer)
```

What I would like to be able to do is to define a property on the owner class that returns a collection (of whatever kind) containing all such components that have been assigned to the owner, i.e.,

```
# Define an Employee object bob and assign it some roles
>>> bob.roles
[<SalesRole(employee='Bob')>, <CustomerSupportRole(employee='Bob')>]
```

I want to accomplish this without hardcoding any references to the types of components that can exist on the owner class -- I want to define new components without changing code anywhere else.

I can more or less accomplish this with an intermediary table mapping owner instances to their components using `generic_relationship` from sqlalchemy-utils. Unfortunately, `generic_relationship` severs SQLAlchemy's automatic cascading of child objects.

Another approach I've tried with help elsewhere was to use SQLAlchemy's event framework to listen for mappings of relationships targeting the owner class (`'mapper_configured'` events). The components would define a backref from themselves to the owner class, and use the `info` parameter to set an arbitrary flag denoting this relationship as a referring to one of the components we want to be made available via this collection. The function registered to catch mapping events would test for this flag, and hypothetically build the collection containing those relationships, but we could never figure out how to make that work.

- It's not important to me that this collection be a SQLAlchemy object via which I can actually write to the database (i.e. `bob.roles.append(SalesmanRole())`. That would be very cool, but just a property serving as a read-only iterable view would suffice.
- It's not important whether the named attribute backrefs exist on the owner class (e.g., `bob.sales_role`. It's fine if they do, but I think the collection is actually more important to me.
- Like I mentioned earlier, cascading is important (unless you want to convince me it's not!).
- Again, it is important that I don't have to hardcode a list of component types anywhere. Whatever magic distinguishes the classes I want to show up in this collection of components from everything else should live in the definition of the components themselves. I want this to be readily extensible as I define new components.

Is there a way to make this work? Or should I be taking a different approach in general -- feel free to tell me this sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is something I suspected but didn't look for hard enough: [class inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html). Simple, elegant, and accomplishes everything I want.

```
class Role(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    role_type = Column(String)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    employee = relationship('Employee', backref='roles')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'employee',
        'polymorphic_on': role_type
    }


class SalesRole(Role):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_role'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'sales_role'
    }
    # Sales-specific attributes, etc.


class CustomerSupportRole(Role):
    __tablename__ = 'support_role'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'support_role'
    }
    # Support-specific attributes, etc.
```